# Javascript Remove Form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I want to only submit post data for value which have changed.

So the way I have been doing this is like this:

```
function submit_form(){
var hd = [];
// hd is a big array that is defined here
// hd ['some id_number'] = 'some value'
// main function
for (var id_number in hd ){
    var x=document.getElementById(id_number).selectedIndex;
    var y=document.getElementById(id_number).options;
    selector_text = y[x].text;
    if (hd[id_number] == selector_text){
        $(id_number).remove();
    }
}
document.forms["my_form"].submit()
}
```

So the goal is that if the selector equals what is in the array, then don't POST the data.

To do this I have been doing the remove function.  Everything up to the remove function works as expected.  However when I look at the post data I still get the selected value for the id_numbers that mach the value in hd.

Is there a better way to remove to prevent it from going to the POST data?  The id.parent.removeChild(id) method didn't work either.

Comment: First of all, you put jQuery, but you're using almost straight javascript, secondly, if you can use jQuery, [this plugin has all your action](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: as id is a number and not an element you would need to use var id = document.getElementById(id_number); id.parent.removeChild(id).

Comment: yea there isn't much jquery here... I intended not to use it at all, but I liked how much simpler the .remove() funciton was so I used it even just for this little line of code

Comment: the solution was the answer below that the id_number needed the Jquery id select pound sign in front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery id selector should begin with a `#`, but yours appears not to:

```
 $('#' + id_number).remove();
```

Your `for-in` loop should be a regular incremental for loop, which is the proper way to iterate an array in JavaScript.  `for-in` loops are typically used for iterating object properties rather than array elements.

```
for (var i=0; i<hd.length; i++) {
  // Access hd[i] in the loop

  var x=document.getElementById(hd[i]).selectedIndex;
  var y=document.getElementById(hd[i]).options;

  selector_text = y[x].text;

  if (hd[i] == selector_text){
     $('#' + hd[i]).remove();
  }
}
```

Since you aren't really using jQuery here except for that line, instead the plain JS version is:

```
var removeMe = document.getElementById(hd[i]);
removeMe.parentNode.removeChild(removeMe);
```

Comment: thanks... I did forget the #... will try with it added in... the id_numbers are not consistent... 1, 3, 4, 5, 10, etc.  so I can't use the regular incremental loop

Comment: @ChristopherH You're iterating and using the array values as in `hd[i]` so it isn't the incrementing variable you are accessing.  You can use it.

Comment: I see... yea I can use it... btw it was the missing '#' that did the trick